# How to put shared memory between c++ and matlab process?

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, mutex, shared-memory

I have separate matlab and Qt c++ program. is it possible that we can share memory between these two. So easily one program can write and other can read with mutex.

Answer (score 0):

You can share memory easily using a memory mapped file. See [`memmapfile`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) in MATLAB and Boost's [Memory Mapped File library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file) for C++. However, it doesn't provide shared mutexes.

An alternative is to create a [mex](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html) wrapper around [C++ Boost shared memory operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory) on the MATLAB side.